# Difference between linear and quasilinear differential equations?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, definition, self-learning

There is a great distinction between the class of linear and nonlinear differential equations concerning their solvability..are there too some general differences, from the same viewpoint, between linear and quasilinear differential equations?

Comment: Aren't quasilinear equations nonlinear?

Comment: https://web.stanford.edu/class/math220a/handouts/firstorder.pdf

Comment: This is what I thought @YuriyS...but in that case, why the class "quasilinear"?